# Unable to build against GLEW on OS X 10.9 Mavericks

Tags: c, xcode, macos, opengl, glew

I'm trying to set up a program using GLEW on OS X 10.9 with Xcode 5.1, but upon trying to build it, I get a huge amount of errors originating from `glew.h`:

```
Build target HelloGL

CompileC /Users/rpowell/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HelloGL-hkapwtszjscyivcyxfphwntzlxmw/Build/Intermediates/HelloGL.build/Debug/HelloGL.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o HelloGL/main.c normal x86_64 c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    cd /Users/rpowell/Projects/HelloGL
    export LANG=en_US.US-ASCII
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x c -arch x86_64 -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -std=gnu99 -fmodules -fmodules-cache-path=/Users/rpowell/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Werror=return-type -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=objc-root-class -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wconditional-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -DDEBUG=1 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk -fasm-blocks -fstrict-aliasing -Wdeprecated-declarations -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -g -Wno-sign-conversion -I/Users/rpowell/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HelloGL-hkapwtszjscyivcyxfphwntzlxmw/Build/Intermediates/HelloGL.build/Debug/HelloGL.build/HelloGL.hmap -I/usr/local/include -I/Users/rpowell/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HelloGL-hkapwtszjscyivcyxfphwntzlxmw/Build/Products/Debug/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/Users/rpowell/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HelloGL-hkapwtszjscyivcyxfphwntzlxmw/Build/Intermediates/HelloGL.build/Debug/HelloGL.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -I/Users/rpowell/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HelloGL-hkapwtszjscyivcyxfphwntzlxmw/Build/Intermediates/HelloGL.build/Debug/HelloGL.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/rpowell/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HelloGL-hkapwtszjscyivcyxfphwntzlxmw/Build/Products/Debug -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/rpowell/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HelloGL-hkapwtszjscyivcyxfphwntzlxmw/Build/Intermediates/HelloGL.build/Debug/HelloGL.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/rpowell/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HelloGL-hkapwtszjscyivcyxfphwntzlxmw/Build/Intermediates/HelloGL.build/Debug/HelloGL.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.dia -c /Users/rpowell/Projects/HelloGL/HelloGL/main.c -o /Users/rpowell/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HelloGL-hkapwtszjscyivcyxfphwntzlxmw/Build/Intermediates/HelloGL.build/Debug/HelloGL.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o

In file included from /Users/rpowell/Projects/HelloGL/HelloGL/main.c:1:
/usr/local/include/GL/glew.h:15043:17: error: declaration of 'PFNGLCOPYTEXSUBIMAGE3DPROC' must be imported from module 'OpenGL.GL3' before it is required
GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLCOPYTEXSUBIMAGE3DPROC __glewCopyTexSubImage3D;
                ^
In module 'OpenGL' imported from /usr/local/include/GL/glew.h:1186:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Headers/gl3.h:1762:25: note: previous declaration is here
typedef void (APIENTRYP PFNGLCOPYTEXSUBIMAGE3DPROC) (GLenum target, GLint level, GLint xoffset, GLint yoffset, GLint zoffset, GLint x, GLint y, GLsizei width, GLsizei height);
                        ^
In file included from /Users/rpowell/Projects/HelloGL/HelloGL/main.c:1:
/usr/local/include/GL/glew.h:15049:17: error: unknown type name 'PFNGLCLIENTACTIVETEXTUREPROC'; did you mean 'PFNGLACTIVETEXTUREPROC'?
GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLCLIENTACTIVETEXTUREPROC __glewClientActiveTexture;
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                PFNGLACTIVETEXTUREPROC
In module 'OpenGL' imported from /usr/local/include/GL/glew.h:1186:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Headers/gl3.h:1778:25: note: 'PFNGLACTIVETEXTUREPROC' declared here
typedef void (APIENTRYP PFNGLACTIVETEXTUREPROC) (GLenum texture);
                        ^
In file included from /Users/rpowell/Projects/HelloGL/HelloGL/main.c:1:
/usr/local/include/GL/glew.h:15057:17: error: unknown type name 'PFNGLLOADTRANSPOSEMATRIXDPROC'
GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLLOADTRANSPOSEMATRIXDPROC __glewLoadTransposeMatrixd;
                ^
/usr/local/include/GL/glew.h:15058:17: error: unknown type name 'PFNGLLOADTRANSPOSEMATRIXFPROC'
GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLLOADTRANSPOSEMATRIXFPROC __glewLoadTransposeMatrixf;
                ^
/usr/local/include/GL/glew.h:15059:17: error: unknown type name 'PFNGLMULTTRANSPOSEMATRIXDPROC'
GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLMULTTRANSPOSEMATRIXDPROC __glewMultTransposeMatrixd;
                ^
/usr/local/include/GL/glew.h:15060:17: error: unknown type name 'PFNGLMULTTRANSPOSEMATRIXFPROC'
GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLMULTTRANSPOSEMATRIXFPROC __glewMultTransposeMatrixf;
                ^
/usr/local/include/GL/glew.h:15061:17: error: unknown type name 'PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD1DPROC'; did you mean 'PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD4XPROC'?
GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD1DPROC __glewMultiTexCoord1d;
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD4XPROC
/usr/local/include/GL/glew.h:13827:28: note: 'PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD4XPROC' declared here
typedef void (GLAPIENTRY * PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD4XPROC) (GLenum target, GLfixed s, GLfixed t, GLfixed r, GLfixed q);
                           ^
/usr/local/include/GL/glew.h:15062:17: error: unknown type name 'PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD1DVPROC'; did you mean 'PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD1HNVPROC'?
GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD1DVPROC __glewMultiTexCoord1dv;
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD1HNVPROC
/usr/local/include/GL/glew.h:12047:28: note: 'PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD1HNVPROC' declared here
typedef void (GLAPIENTRY * PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD1HNVPROC) (GLenum target, GLhalf s);
                           ^
/usr/local/include/GL/glew.h:15063:17: error: unknown type name 'PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD1FPROC'; did you mean 'PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD4XPROC'?
GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD1FPROC __glewMultiTexCoord1f;
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD4XPROC
/usr/local/include/GL/glew.h:13827:28: note: 'PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD4XPROC' declared here
typedef void (GLAPIENTRY * PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD4XPROC) (GLenum target, GLfixed s, GLfixed t, GLfixed r, GLfixed q);
                           ^
/usr/local/include/GL/glew.h:15064:17: error: unknown type name 'PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD1FVPROC'; did you mean 'PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD1HNVPROC'?
GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD1FVPROC __glewMultiTexCoord1fv;
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD1HNVPROC
/usr/local/include/GL/glew.h:12047:28: note: 'PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD1HNVPROC' declared here
typedef void (GLAPIENTRY * PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD1HNVPROC) (GLenum target, GLhalf s);
                           ^
/usr/local/include/GL/glew.h:15065:17: error: unknown type name 'PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD1IPROC'
GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD1IPROC __glewMultiTexCoord1i;
                ^
/usr/local/include/GL/glew.h:15066:17: error: unknown type name 'PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD1IVPROC'
GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD1IVPROC __glewMultiTexCoord1iv;
                ^
/usr/local/include/GL/glew.h:15067:17: error: unknown type name 'PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD1SPROC'; did you mean 'PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD4XPROC'?
GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD1SPROC __glewMultiTexCoord1s;
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD4XPROC
/usr/local/include/GL/glew.h:13827:28: note: 'PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD4XPROC' declared here
typedef void (GLAPIENTRY * PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD4XPROC) (GLenum target, GLfixed s, GLfixed t, GLfixed r, GLfixed q);
                           ^
/usr/local/include/GL/glew.h:15068:17: error: unknown type name 'PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD1SVPROC'; did you mean 'PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD1HNVPROC'?
GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD1SVPROC __glewMultiTexCoord1sv;
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD1HNVPROC
/usr/local/include/GL/glew.h:12047:28: note: 'PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD1HNVPROC' declared here
typedef void (GLAPIENTRY * PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD1HNVPROC) (GLenum target, GLhalf s);
                           ^
/usr/local/include/GL/glew.h:15069:17: error: unknown type name 'PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD2DPROC'; did you mean 'PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD4XPROC'?
GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD2DPROC __glewMultiTexCoord2d;
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD4XPROC
/usr/local/include/GL/glew.h:13827:28: note: 'PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD4XPROC' declared here
typedef void (GLAPIENTRY * PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD4XPROC) (GLenum target, GLfixed s, GLfixed t, GLfixed r, GLfixed q);
                           ^
/usr/local/include/GL/glew.h:15070:17: error: unknown type name 'PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD2DVPROC'; did you mean 'PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD2HNVPROC'?
GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD2DVPROC __glewMultiTexCoord2dv;
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD2HNVPROC
/usr/local/include/GL/glew.h:12049:28: note: 'PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD2HNVPROC' declared here
typedef void (GLAPIENTRY * PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD2HNVPROC) (GLenum target, GLhalf s, GLhalf t);
                           ^
/usr/local/include/GL/glew.h:15071:17: error: unknown type name 'PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD2FPROC'; did you mean 'PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD4XPROC'?
GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD2FPROC __glewMultiTexCoord2f;
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD4XPROC
/usr/local/include/GL/glew.h:13827:28: note: 'PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD4XPROC' declared here
typedef void (GLAPIENTRY * PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD4XPROC) (GLenum target, GLfixed s, GLfixed t, GLfixed r, GLfixed q);
                           ^
/usr/local/include/GL/glew.h:15072:17: error: unknown type name 'PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD2FVPROC'; did you mean 'PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD2HNVPROC'?
GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD2FVPROC __glewMultiTexCoord2fv;
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD2HNVPROC
/usr/local/include/GL/glew.h:12049:28: note: 'PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD2HNVPROC' declared here
typedef void (GLAPIENTRY * PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD2HNVPROC) (GLenum target, GLhalf s, GLhalf t);
                           ^
/usr/local/include/GL/glew.h:15073:17: error: unknown type name 'PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD2IPROC'
GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLMULTITEXCOORD2IPROC __glewMultiTexCoord2i;
                ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
```

The program itself is very simple, only slightly modified from the [GLFW documentation's example code](http://www.glfw.org/documentation.html):

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    GLFWwindow* window;

    // Initialize the library
    if (!glfwInit())
        return -1;

    // Specify the minimum OpenGL version
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 2);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);

    // Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context
    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    // Make the window's context current
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    printf("GL Version: %s", glGetString(GL_VERSION));

    // Loop until the user closes the window
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        // Render here
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        // Swap front and back buffers
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        // Poll for and process events
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

Some more details about this project's configuration that may help:

- GLEW is installed through Homebrew, built from the latest tarball on the project's sourceforge page
- I've changed a few build settings in the project

  - *Always Search User Paths* is set to `YES`
  - *User Header Search Paths* is set to `/usr/local/include`
- The project links against `libGLEW.1.10.0.dylib` and `libglfw.3.0.dylib`

If anyone has encountered this before, or otherwise has a solution to this issue I'd very much appreciate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like **rpowell** mentioned above, the way to avoid this error on recent versions of XCode  is by doing the following:
PS: (I solved this on my project running XCode 8.2.1 and OS X El Capitain 10.11.6):

**On the Project tab, select your project by single-clicking on its name (It is the blue icon in my example)**

[image]

**After that, single-click on Build Setting tab and make sure you have the following options selected: *All* and *Combined***

[image]

**Finally, search for 'enable modules' on the search menu, and when it shows Enable Modules(C and Objective-C), just mark no**

[image]

After that you should be 'hopefully' able to compile your code and get it running.

Answer (score 16):

Alright, some digging around helped me figure out exactly what Clang is complaining about. Looks like the version of Clang that ships with Xcode 5.1 includes support for [Modules](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/Modules.html); which are very cool and interesting and solve a bunch of problems, but also completely break GLEW.

By setting the *Enable Modules (C and Objective C)* build option to `NO`, everything works as it did in prior versions and GLEW works as expected.